# PyThon How do I pass a object to another class?

Tags: python

I just want to access some_object within class hello: def GET()

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        return some_object


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = []
    some_object = ParentObj.func(data)

    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Comment: @S.Lott: blame the web.py tutorial for the class, and web.py itself for the method, not the OP.

Comment: some_object is an instance of ParentObj.func(data)

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks.  I didn't look deeply enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `some_object` a member of the class itself.

Under your `'__main__'` section, set `some_object` as a class member of the `hello` class, like so:

```
hello.some_object = some_object
```

Then change `hello.GET` to return the member of the class:

```
class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        return self.some_object
```